# How to detect if mouse pointer is out of my section

Tags: javascript, html

I just created split screen in css but i want to change in like when pointer goes out of section code that handle is come to it's original place like in realform when it is on refresh time. I want to make it like this https://www.corsair.com/eu/en/specalpha

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  let wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  let topLayer = wrapper.querySelector('.top');
  let handle = wrapper.querySelector('.handle');
  let skew = 0;
  let delta = 0;
  let isOnDiv = false;
  
  if (wrapper.className.indexOf('skewed') != -1) {
    skew = 1000;
  }

  function positionHandler(e) {
    if ((e.clientX) && (e.clientY)) {
      delta = (e.clientX - window.innerWidth / 2) * 0.5;
      handle.style.left = e.clientX + delta + 'px';
      topLayer.style.width = e.clientX + skew + delta + 'px';

    } else if (e.targetTouches) {
      delta = (e.targetTouches[0].clientX - window.innerWidth / 2) * 0.5;
      handle.style.left = e.targetTouches[0].clientX + delta + 'px';
      topLayer.style.width = e.targetTouches[0].clientX + skew + delta + 'px';
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };
  
  wrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', positionHandler, false);
  wrapper.addEventListener('touchstart', positionHandler, false);
  wrapper.addEventListener('touchmove', positionHandler, false);
  wrapper.addEventListener("mouseleave", resetPositionHandler, false);

  function resetPositionHandler(e) {
      handle.style.left = '50%';
      topLayer.style.width = 'calc(50vw + 1000px)';
  }
});
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.6;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}



#wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 55vw; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.layer{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 55vw;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.layer .content-wrap{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 55vw;
    
}

.layer .content-body{
    width: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    color: #ffff;
}
.layer img{
    position: absolute;
    width: 35%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.layer h1{
    font-size: 2em;

}

.bottom{
    background: #222;
    z-index: 1;
}

.bottom .content-body{
    right: 5%;
}



.bottom h1{
    color: #FDAB00;
}

.top{
    background: #eee;
    color: #222;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 50vw;
}

.top .content-body{
    left: 5%;
    color: #222;
}



.handle{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: #FDAB00;
    width: 5px;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 3;
}

.skewed .handle{
    top: 50%;
    transform: rotate(30deg) translateY(-50%);
    height: 200%;
    transform-origin: top;
}

.skewed .top{
    transform: skew(-30deg);
    margin-left: -1000px;
    width: calc(50vw + 1000px);
}

.skewed .top .content-wrap{
    transform: skew(30deg);
    margin-left: 1000px;
}


div.angrytext {
    font-size:70px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#4794D3;
    width:300px;
    margin:90px auto;
    
    -webkit-animation: jump 4s linear 0s infinite normal ;
    animation: jump 4s linear 0s infinite normal ;
   }

.cs_logo{
    margin-right: 30px;
}
   
@-webkit-keyframes jump {
    0%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    }
    13%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    }
    40%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
    }
    50%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    }
    60%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
    }
    80%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    }
    100%{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

@keyframes jump {
    0%{
    transform: translateY(0);
    }
    13%{
    transform: translateY(0);
    }
    40%{
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    }
    50%{
    transform: translateY(0);
    }
    60%{
    transform: translateY(-5px);
    }
    80%{
    transform: translateY(0);
    }
    100%{
    transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
div.card{
    background:linear-gradient(135deg, #201f24 0%,#40304d 100%);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgb(49, 49, 49);

}

@media(max-width:768px){
    body{
        font-size: 75%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Split Screen</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="wrapper" class="skewed">
        <div class="layer bottom">
            <div class="content-wrap">
                <div class="content-body">
                    <h1>Machine</h1>
                    <p>The machine side of the game is really complex yet easy !</p>
                    <p1>The machines are specially crafted to challenge your human brain to it's core</p1>
                    <p2>Only the ones with real human intelligence can solve them being too technical is sometimes a hurdle itself</p2>
                    
                </div>
                <img src="img/pic01.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="layer top">
                <div class="content-wrap">
                    <div class="content-body">
                        <h1>Human</h1>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis architecto consequuntur officia voluptatibus odio maxime quos reprehenderit vero iste eos!</p>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/pic02.png" alt="">
                </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="handle"></div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="card-deck">
            <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem; height: 25rem">
        
                <div class='angrytext'><img class="cs_logo" src="img/cs_logo.png" height=100px width=150px></div>
        
                <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text" style="color:#ffffff">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    </div>       
             </div>
        
          <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem; height: 25rem">
        
                <div class='angrytext'><img class="cs_logo" src="img/cs_logo.png" height=100px width=150px></div>
        
                <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text" style="color:#ffffff">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    </div>       
             </div>

         <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem; height: 25rem">
        
                <div class='angrytext'><img class="cs_logo" src="img/cs_logo.png" height=100px width=150px></div>
        
                <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text" style="color:#ffffff">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    </div>       
          </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you guys help me to do this things actully i don't know wwhat i had to search and try

Comment: Maybe one of these events is what you want? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event#See_also

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to reset it to the initial values on 'mouseleave' event

```
wrapper.addEventListener("mouseleave", resetPositionHandler, false);

function resetPositionHandler(e) {
    handle.style.left = '50%';
    topLayer.style.width = 'calc(50vw + 1000px)';
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not working also it stopped that hover effect

Comment: I updated the answer, I think this is what you want

Comment: Please can you help me to wright content both side of image?

Comment: I need to write content like bottom on top layer and also on bottom layer  like top layer. I just edited my code can you help me to make it more clear

Comment: Hi please can you help me to make it responsive?